# SQL in VBA WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have been trying to add additional filter criteria to my WHERE clause in sql VBA. The previous select statement works fine, but I can't seem to get the updated WHERE clause to work. Here's what I have:

```
WHERE tblretirements.Applicationcancelled = 'No' 
    AND tblretirements.FirstPayDate IS NULL 
    OR tblretiremetns.FirstPayDate BETWEEN 'now()' & 'Beginning of Prior Fiscal Year'
```

I am not that familiar with the `BETWEEN` statement and am positive that I am messing that up. I need to have the code dynamically reference today's date and the beginning of the prior fiscal year, which is 6/1/2017 right now. Can someone please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sytax of `BETWEEN` statement is `field_name BETWEEN aaa AND bbb`,
**NOT** `field_name BETWEEN aaa & bbb`.

modify your code

```
tblretiremetns.FirstPayDate BETWEEN 'now()' & 'Beginning of Prior Fiscal Year'
```

to

```
tblretiremetns.FirstPayDate BETWEEN date() AND dateserial(year(date()) - 1, 6, 1)
```

Which `now()` function returns date and time, and `date()` function returns date only.